# Quicksort Analysis

Tags: sorting, quicksort

Question:

Here's a modification of quick sort: whenever we have ten items or fewer in a sublist, we sort the sublist using selection sort rather than further recursing with quicksort. Does this change the big-oh time complexity of quicksort? Explain.

In my opinion the big-oh time complexity would change. We know that selection sort is O(n^2) and therefore sorting the sublist of ten items or fewer would take O(n^2). Until we get to a sublist that has ten or fewer items we would use quicksort and keep partitioning the list. So in the end we would have O( nlogn + n^2) which is O(n^2).

Am I correct? If not, could someone explain why?

Comment: you're wrong, selection sort in this case is not O(N^2), but O(1), because number of elements is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the time complexity is actually unaffected is that 10 is a constant term. No matter how large the total array is, it always takes a constant amount of time to sort subarrays of size 10 or less. If you are sorting a list with one million elements, that constant 10 is going to play a very small role in the actual time it takes to sort the list (most of the time will be spent partitioning the original array into subarrays recursively).

If sorting a list of 10 elements takes constant time, partitioning the array at each recursive step is linear, and you end up with log n subarrays of 10 items or fewer, you end up with O(n log n + log n), which is the same as O(n log n).

Saying that selection sort is O(n^2) means that the running time of the algorithm increases quadratically with the size of the input. Running selection sort on an array with a constant number of elements will always take constant time on its own, but if you were to compare the running time of selection sort on arrays of varying sizes, you would see a quadratic increase in the running time as input size varies linearly.

Answer (score 0):

The big O complexity does not change. Please read up on the Master Method (aka Master Theorem) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

If you think through the algorithm as the size of the sorting list grows exceptionally large the time to sort the final ten in any given recursion substree will make insignificant contributions to overall running time.